# Which API can I use for tracking the position of animal in one or more images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-recognition

I'd like to build an application for tracking the position of a given animal (e.g. a cat) in a series of images.

Is there any off-the-shelf API I could use?

Azure has some Vision APIs, but it seems to me they can't be used to get the position of something in an image.

Comment: When you say position, do you mean something like bounding box coordinates around the animal? The most “off-the-shelf” API I’ve seen is Fast.Ai. They’re always implementing SOTA algorithms, and expanding regularly. They also have lectures for free online outlining their code. It’s a little bit “black box” but might work well for your use case.

Comment: Thx. Just to confirm, this is their site, right: https://docs.fast.ai/. I'm totally fresh to AI, (just want use it on a personal project) so I thought I better double-check.

Comment: I believe this is their main site: https://www.fast.ai. I suppose the one you posted is documentation which will probably be useful. But I think under the MOOC section of the main site you can watch video lectures with examples of their API (and a little theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FastAI](https://www.fast.ai) is the most “out of the box” API for this type of task.

For video examples (and a little theory) check out the MOOC section of their site.

[Practical Deep Learning](http://course.fast.ai/) and [Cutting Edge Deep Learning](http://course18.fast.ai/part2.html) are the two sections most relevant to you.

But if you want a working implementation check out [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/qfgaohao/pytorch-ssd) that implements SSD for your purposes. I can’t say how simple the API is but it does what you are seeking (in pure PyTorch).

**note**: FastAI was originally built on top of PyTorch (although they are expanding out now), so you’ll be using PyTorch and need a rough idea of how to work with tensors. Most of the challenges are already implemented in their api. Installing their library will automatically install PyTorch.